# how do u define an object inside of python interms of is statement

Tags: python

is this what it means that x and y are the same object not just the values that they are basically connected ? 
or I'm getting the 'is' statement wrong

```
>>> x=[2,8]
>>> y=x
>>> x.reverse()
>>> y
[8, 2]
>>> y is x
True
```

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html is a great pycon presentation (or just read it; the blog post contains everything in the video) that tells everything everyone absolutely needs to know about names in Python to really understand the language.

Comment: @Wooble will do right away ,thanx for recommendation ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it exactly right on all counts, they are the same object, and that is what `is` is meant to show. `=` does not make a copy. One way to copy the list is with `y = list(x)`.

Comment: `y = x[:]` also works

Comment: Also `y = x.copy()`

Comment: The difference between shallow and deep copy may be a good reading to understand this... in depth: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

That's right, they are exactly the same object - they a sharing the same memory address. If you modify one, you modify them both, like so:

```
x = [2, 8]
y = x
x.reverse()

print(y) # [8, 2]
```

If you don't want this you can make a copy using `y = x[:]`.